# Chamada Assincrona a um RestFull WebService

Tags: java, android, web-service, restful, assincronismo

Preciso fazer uma chamada ao WebService em Android, e com outra classe chamá-la. No final mostrar no *design* a resposta obtida pelo ws. Eu já fiz o WebService só que a parte do "assincrona" não está a dar.

Este é o meu WebService, recebe três *strings*:

```
public class WebServiceRestFull extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    protected ProgressDialog dialog;


    public String wsURL;
    public String wsFunction;
    public String wsInput;

    public int codigoHTTP;
    public String mensagemHTTP;
    public String strResposta;


    public WebServiceRestFull(Context act)
    {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(act);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Aguarde por favor...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        if (dialog.isShowing())
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        //chamada ao webservice e retorna uma string

        //return resposta do webservice;
    }      
}
```

Do lado do "Android Activity" eu chamo esta classe assincrona do seguinte modo:

```
WebServiceRestFull web = new WebServiceRestFull(this);
web.wsURL = "http://someurl.com/rest/etc";
web.wsFunction = "login";
web.wsInput = "mike";
web.execute();
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

O problema é que não está a fazer de fato uma chamada assíncrona e os resultado quase sempre não são recebidos pelo WebService.

Existe alguma maneira mais simples de fazer isto ou estou a fazer errado nalgum lado como a chamada ao WebService ou a própria classe do WebService?

Comment: Um bom exemplo para começar esta aqui.

http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-restful-webservice-tutorial-part-1/

Comment: A resposta é passada ao método `onPostExecute()` através do parâmetro `result`. É nesse método que deve tratar a resposta.

Comment: Você não está fazendo nada no código acima, você apagou o código no `doInBackground` ? Do jeito que está, você só exibe um dialog e fecha

Answer (score 0):

Miguel, não sou especialista em Java, mas considerando o conceito de Threads você está utilizando o "Thread.sleep(1000)" por qual motivo?

Se sua classe está fazendo uma requisição assíncrona e você está aguardando um segundo por ela, então provavelmente não está implementado como deveria, pelos seguintes motivos:

1) A Activity é síncrona por exato 1 segundo com a classe assíncrona esta não é a forma correta de lidar com o retorno de uma classe assíncrona.

2) Não foi apresentado nenhum código para recuperação de resultados na sua questão, logo parto do entendimento que você está fazendo isso logo após o Thread.sleep, o que nem sempre será suficiente.

Portanto recomendo que implementa alguma forma (eventos?) de detectar quando sua classe assíncrona conclui a busca de informações no WS e então recuperar o valor desejado, de forma que isto não impeça a execução contínua da Activity (isso sim seria assincronismo).

Não colocarei nenhum exemplo em código pois minha contribuição em Java limita-se a teoria aplicada também a outras linguagens.

Espero ter ajudado, amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Estou em um projeto parecido. O WS vai retornar os dados para a sua activity principal.

O jeito de resolver pelo AssyncTask
que realmente faz o que você quer, ao invés de esperar o tempo da thread e sim fazer pelo que vai acontecer depois. 
olha as respostas dessa pergunta sobre usar Thread ou assync ou handler https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964011/handler-vs-asynctask-vs-thread

Tá aqui um exemplo do assynctask 
https://jsfiddle.net/nzqLxa5v/
mas esse é do meu projeto, ai vai de vc adaptar. 
Mas o que ocorre ai é vc entender o doInBackground e onPostExecute

Comment: Em vez de colocar um link, coloque o código directamente na resposta.

Comment: Coloquei  o link para não poluir o tópico e não perder tempo dando espaços já que a intenção é só ajudar

Comment: O código não é poluição, a grande maioria das resposta tem código associado e ele deve ser postado. Para formatar o código não necessita de introduzir espaços linha a linha, basta seleccioná-lo e clicar ctrl + k.

Comment: Não sabia disto, sou novo aqui ainda.. Não sabia desse ctrl k. Valeu obrigado.